# Texmaker and .pdftex file type

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I am trying to compile a `.pdftex` file type using TeXmaker. There doesn't seem to be too much on `.pdftex` files on the internet and I can't seem to compile it.

Does anyone know how to handle `.pdftex` file types and in particular how to handle them using TeXmaker or LyX? I think they were originally created by my co-author using Scientific Workplace.

As a disclaimer, I am not a very proficient user of LaTeX, normally I generate my `.tex` files in TeXmaker and then either press F6 (pdfLaTeX) or F2, F4, F8 (Latex, Dvi->Ps, Ps-PDF) to generate my final PDF file.

Comment: Without some informations about the content of such a file it is impossible to answer such a question.

Comment: As Ulirke says, we need more information here to have a chance to answer.